# Is default scoped binding preferred to Singleton binding for stateless objects?

Tags: dependency-injection, guice

According to the [Guice wiki page](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fgoogle%2Fguice%2Fwiki%2FScopes%23choosing-a-scope&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNFu-v4Zzx3_m6lPaB7nQgWEfdRvIA), unscoped binding is preferred to Singleton for stateless objects.

I do not agree with the statement though because:

1. Singleton scope gives more information to developers. Developer can assume singleton objects are thread-safe and they can be injected without using Provider most of the time.
2. Creating an unscoped object can be expensive because of dependencies to other unscoped objects.
3. Cyclic dependency of unscoped objects can only be resolved with Providers, which could lead to weird behavior.
   e.g. A depends on B, B depends on Provider, and some method f() in A invokes B which invokes some method in A, then a new instance of A and B will be created each time f() is called.
4. When injecting a Request Scoped object into unscoped objects, it is hard to tell if you need a provider or not because the life cycle of unscoped object is unknown.

Could someone explain why is default scoped preferred to singleton scope for stateless objects?

Comment: Also, the wiki page seems quite clear "_If the object is **stateless** and **inexpensive to create**, scoping is unnecessary_" (emphasis theirs). That seems to nullify all your arguments.

Comment: Unscoped, or default scoped, means binding with no scope notion. Guice will construct a new instance of the class each time the binding is injected.

Comment: sorry for the typos :p

Answer (score 2):

There's one big and important reason for the preference to unscoped objects instead of singleton objects: *Singleton objects can never be garbage collected, nor can the entire transitive tree of objects to which they hold references.* Their construction needs to be synchronized (to prevent race conditions during creation), and then they remain in memory for the entire lifetime of the Injector.

This is particularly an issue because, in a production environment, [all Guice singletons are eager](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Scopes#eager-singletons) regardless of whether they're bound `asEagerSingleton`. This means that in production your memory commitment of your singleton tree starts when the Injector is created, and often lasts until the application closes.

Using Singletons for everything may cause slower startup and larger memory requirements than judiciously choosing singletons.

Of course, if the object and its dependencies are all stateless, the memory footprint of each object is pretty light. However, if your singleton depends on an object that depends on an object that depends on a database, then that database and its memory will be required on startup and never freed.

---

```
injector ___________________TIME_________________________\
creation                                                 /

|---------------------SINGLETON-------------------------->
   |----------REQUEST A------------|   |---REQUEST B----->
      |-UNSCOPED C-| |-UNSCOPED D-|      |-UNSCOPED E-|
```

Scopes track roughly to the lifetime of the object, and the goal is to *avoid injecting a narrower-scoped object into a wider-scoped object* (say, keeping around unscoped object C, which might be relevant to request A but not request B). To do so would be a *scope-widening injection*.

When you refer to unscoped objects, think of them as ephemeral or disposable, and having the narrowest scope possible. This makes it particularly easy to make stateless objects unscoped, because it doesn't matter which instance you have.

Those unscoped objects are also free to inject any object in the graph without using providers, on the assumption that the unscoped object will always have the shorter lifetime compared to any other dependency you pick. By contrast, a singleton must use providers for all of its non-singleton dependencies, because it will absolutely outlive any non-singleton it depends on.

This should make it clear when you need Providers, as you allude to in #1 and #4 above.

---

In summary, I can only direct you back to [the section you linked](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Scopes#choosing-a-scope): Unless you have a good reason (state, expensive construction, or resource management) you should probably leave your injectors unscoped.

Comment: A says, use `x` unless `Y`. B says, use `y` unless `X`. :)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, Jeff!

Comment: I feel the time/memory consumption might not be an advantage for unscoped object though. Imagine a server application with high throughput, it might need to construct many stateless unscoped objects, and it is likely that multiple unscoped object instances of the same class stay in memory all the time during peak hours. For singletons, there will be no construction and GC overhead once server starts, and there will be exactly 1 instance in memory.

Comment: @user607722 What you just described is exactly why you won't find a rule like "always use singletons" or "never use singletons". Each one will be its own judgment call depending on how dep-heavy it is and how likely it is to be needed constantly. Hopefully I've helped explain _why_ they are _preferred_, and you can use your engineering judgment to apply the pros and cons to your particular dependencies.